# Formatting for xml tag into a soap request using BeautifulSoup with Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add a tag into an xml file. When the tag is stored as a variable I noticed that the `< />` characters were decoded to `&lt; &gt;` when I tried to append() it to the xml.

```
import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

no_email = '<errorEmailNotification enabled="false"/>'
bs = BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
header = bs.find("S:Header")
header.append(no_email)
print(header.prettify())
```

which results in this output

```
<S:Header>
 <Some Header info/>
 &lt;errorEmailNotification enabled="false"/&gt;
</S:Header>
```

I used `html.unescape()` on the below variable and it looks fine when printed out

```
no_email = html.unescape('&lt;errorEmailNotification enabled="false"/&gt;')
print(no_email)

<errorEmailNotification enabled="false"/>
```

but when I pass `no_email` into a specific tag using beautifulsoup it still looks exactly as it is written in the string and I'm not sure why.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
no_email = html.unescape('&lt;errorEmailNotification enabled="false"/&gt;')
bs = BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
header = bs.find("S:Header")
header.append(no_email)
print(header.prettify())
```

output:

```
<S:Header>
 <Some Header Info/>
 &lt;errorEmailNotification enabled="false"/&gt;
</S:Header>
```

How can I use this correctly so that I get this result:

```
    <S:Header>
     <Some Header Info/>
     <errorEmailNotification enabled="false"/>
    </S:Header>
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup lets you manipulate the object model.  If you want to add new objects, then you need to add them as BS objects, like with `new_tag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `new_tag()` element instead of a string:

```
import bs4
from io import StringIO

xml = """<root xmlns:S ="something">
<S:Header>
 <Some_Header_info/>
</S:Header></root>"""
f = StringIO(xml)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "xml")
no_email = soup.new_tag("errorEmailNotification", enabled="false")
header = soup.find("S:Header")
header.append(no_email)
print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:S="something">
 <S:Header>
  <Some_Header_info/>
  <errorEmailNotification enabled="false"/>
 </S:Header>
</root>
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked! Not sure what the purpose of StringIO is though.

Comment: @iNeedScissors61, it simulate a file stream. If you read a file, you don’t need it.